# Theorems discovered without observation

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, big-list

Can you name me a few theorems that were discovered without first observing some special cases? In other words, by brute logic: Starting from the known and logically deducing the unknown?

EDIT: As an example, we all know that the quadratic reciprocity law was not discovered in this way.

Comment: It's a bit excessive to say "we all know" how the quadratic reciprocity law was found through experimentation.

Comment: That $\sum_{n \geq 1} 1/n^2 = \pi^2/6$ was never conjectured before Euler found the value. Of course people before Euler could numerically estimate the series, but the decimal estimate gave no hint about such a nice closed form expression.

Answer (score 2):

[Jones' index rigidity formula](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~dpenneys/TemperleyLieb.pdf) comes to mind. In fact, there was no way to "observe" it in the special cases. It was widely believed that the index could take all values between $1$ and $\infty$- so the theorem came as a surprise.
(The theorem states that the index takes values in a discrete series between $1$ and $4$).

Comment: @AnalysisIncarnate: "The guy" or any other person had no idea about it. In fact von Neumann had thought the opposite. It's a well documented story- through various interviews.